# casting one dimension array as two dimension array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, casting

I need to create a 2 dimensional array with dynamically allocated memory (both dimensions will be set at runtime), but for efficiency purposes I want to create a one dimension version of it with a contiguous allocated memory, and yet again somehow want to use it as a two dimensional array. Is there a way to use casting to implement this. 
The usage I want to implement is as below, which clearly does not work.
Best,

```
int size = 4;
int* arr = new int[size];
arr[0] = 10;
arr[1] = 11;
arr[2] = 12;
arr[3] = 13;
cout << (int[][2])arr[1][1] << endl;
```

Comment: Why do you intend to manage the memory explicitly? It's not C++ idiomatic to use naked arrays. For your case there would be boost::multidim (though I know many people frown upon boost, for various reasons). http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I think Codor's solution is in best compliance with the coding style of C++, I would like to share my solution done in C-style.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

typedef int (*pint2)[2]; //pint2 is a pointer to an array of 2 ints

int main()
{
    int arr[4] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
    pint2 parr = (pint2)arr;
    std::cout << parr[0][0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << parr[0][1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << parr[1][0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << parr[1][1] << std::endl;

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps! (or at least that you found this interesting :/)

EDIT: And for arrays of variable lengths!

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int arr[12] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };
    const int sizeofarr = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]); //Number of elements in array

    {
        const int numofrows = 2; //Number of rows
        const int numofcolumns = sizeofarr/numofrows; //Number of columns
        typedef int (*pinta)[sizeofarr/numofrows]; //A 2D array of columns of 2

        pinta parr = (pinta)arr;
        for(int i = 0; i < numofrows; ++i)
            for(int j = 0; j < numofcolumns; ++j)
                std::cout << parr[i][j] << std::endl;
    }

    {
        const int numofrows = 3; //Number of rows
        const int numofcolumns = sizeofarr/numofrows; //Number of columns
        typedef int (*pinta)[sizeofarr/numofrows]; //A 2D array of columns of 3

        pinta parr = (pinta)arr;
        for(int i = 0; i < numofrows; ++i)
            for(int j = 0; j < numofcolumns; ++j)
                std::cout << parr[i][j] << std::endl;
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nard, none of the dimensions are known at compile time so I cannot use typedef int (*pint2)[2]. Yet, it is interesting.

Comment: @Efe Edited to your liking. :D

Comment: And as per usual, they must be homogeneous.

Comment: this might really help Nard. Cheers.

Comment: That makes me really happy :D Cheers!

Comment: In fact I can use casting ((pinta))arr[i][j]  to achieve what I need without creating an extra pointer (parr).

Comment: Yeah you can do that too. But you're gonna have to do that everywhere you use `arr` as a 2D array :/

Answer (score 2):

Since this is C++, you could wrap the one-dimensional array (which is necessary due to the locality requirement) and overload `operator()` to permit two-dimensional acccess using some suitable index calculation.

Comment: So there seems to be no solution using builtin type casting. I shall consider overloading method.

Answer (score 0):

g++ compiles the following slightly changed line (operator precedence) with -fpermissive:

```
cout << ((int[][2])arr)[1][1] << endl;
```

I assume that it is UB (anybody?) but I also assume that it will work just fine on all "common" platforms.

Comment: somehow it did not in osx.

Comment: g++ (GCC) 4.8.3
Target: i686-pc-cygwin; also `-fpermissive` was needed. But I find Nard's cast much better. It is what one should do (if one wants to do it).

Comment: Oh; you mean it compiled but crashed?

Comment: I asumme "that it will work just fine on all "common" platforms" ... **with gcc** ;-).